# Changing from tinyint to smallint with a database full of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tinyint

A peace of mind question really.

I have a field in my database that uses `tinyint(3)` as the integer value. I've now realised that this is to low a value and want to change it to `smallint`. If I change this using phpMyAdmin, will any of the current data be effected? I've tried it locally and seems fine but I prefer to run it by people with more database experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data *will* be affected in a way -- it will be changed from `tinyint` to `smallint`, so in effect the entire column will undergo a `CAST` operation. But it *won't* be affected in the sense of experiencing any truncation or data loss.

Because `tinyint` is a subset of `smallint`, this cast operation shouldn't cause any problems. If you attempted to cast a `tinyint` value to `smallint` in a query, you would never expect that to fail, because every `tinyint` is also a `smallint`. The same logic applies when modifying your table schema.

Comment: That's good enough for me. Thank you both for your help, sorry I can't mark them both as right.

Comment: I doubt seriously if phpmyadmin will do the necessary ALTER table.

Answer (score 7):

You can use below query:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY Id SMALLINT
```

Also make sure if there is any constraint attached to the column then you need to first drop those constraint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not really sure what constraints are but I haven't manually set any up. My table is very simple with one of the fields (called 'score') holding a score. This was initially set to tinyint(3) but it turns out this isn't big enough. I just changed it in phpmyadmin but this should be fine shouldn't it?

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what it currently says about Id.  Examples: `NOT NULL`, `AUTO_INCREMENT`, ... -- Those need to be repeated in the ALTER, pelase you will lose them.